# Buscar novo valor de uma variável no LocalStorage após voltar para a view usando $state.go();

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Eu tenho uma view que usa uma variável do LocalStorage chamada de *Entity*.

```
/* Entity Service */ 
.factory('EntityService', function (){  
  return {
    getEntity : function(){
      return JSON.parse(window.localStorage['entity'] || false);
    }
  };
})

/* Route definition */
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl',
  resolve : {
    Entity : function(EntityService){
      return EntityService.getEntity();
    }
  }
})

/* AppCtrl*/
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,Entity) {
  $scope.model = {
   entity : Entity
  };
})
```

```
/* AppCtrl (view) */    
<ion-view view-title="{{ model.entity.name }}">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="padding">Home</div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

```
/* EntitiesCtrl */
$scope.setEntity = function(entity){
  window.localStorage['entity'] = JSON.stringify(entity);
  $state.go('app.home');
}
```

```
/* EntitiesCtrl (view)*/
<div class="list">      
  <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="setEntity(entity)" ng-repeat="entity in model.entities">
    <img src="img/entities/{{ entity.logo }}">
    <h2>{{ entity.name }} - {{ entity.acronym }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entity.city.name }} - {{ entity.city.state.acronym }}</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

O valor da variável *entity* é alterada dentro do Controller Entities, mas quando o `$state.go('app.home')` é chamado, o valor da variável é alterado mas a view continua com o valor antigo da variável.

```
{{ model.entity.name }}
```

Quando o `$state.go('app.home')` é executado, o controller não roda novamente (conferi com um `console.log();`).

O que eu preciso fazer para que o controller busque o novo valor da variável todas as vezes que `$state.go('app.home')` for chamado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não mostrou onde está sendo usado o controller Entities, acredito que você possa estar em um state diferente de `app.home`.

Portanto, acredito que o que você deseja é a opção `reload` do método [`$state.go()`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go):

```
$state.go('app.home', null, {
    reload: true
});
```

Com esta, os controllers vão ser recarregados caso eles já estejam presentes no state/view atual.

Outra forma de fazer o mesmo, caso você já esteja no state `app.home`, é usar [`$state.reload()`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_reload) diretamente.

Answer (score 0):

A questão maior é que você precisa utilizar o `$window` ao invés do `window`.

```
$window.localStorage
```

Faça o teste com o exemplo acima.

Utilize os métodos get,set e remove, para manipular os dados da `localStorage`.